# Навигация с помощью jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, меню

На странице имеется блок `<div id="menu">`  и `<div id="content">`. Содержимое блока content (page1.php, page2.php,...) загружается по ссылкам с помощью jquery load. Меню зависит от загруженной страницы. Как можно сделать, чтобы меню выводилось в зависимости от содержимого блока `<div id="content">`?

Comment: Пример можно увидеть?

Comment: "Меню зависит от загруженной страницы."
Текст меню разный или вид меню (активный пункт, например, меняется ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждая ссылка на страницу должна иметь свой id, например ссылка на `page1.php` будет иметь `id="page1"`.
Дальше вы просто пишите:

```
$('#page1').click() {
    //если нажали на page1.php
}
$('#page2').click() {
    //если нажали на page2.php
}
```